# Ubuntu 20.04 - RTP Sound horrible with PulseAudio

Tags: pulseaudio, 20.04, gstreamer

just upgraded some of my computers to Ubuntu 20.04, also tried with fresh install, in all case the pulseaudio rtp receive module is giving me very poor sound. Did some testing with vlc as a client to open the RTP stream, works well then.

In journalctl when loading the module-rtp-recv I see :

```
pulseaudio[2514]: Failed to set scheduler settings: Permission denied
```

Easily reproducible on a single machine :

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MyNullSink
pacmd load-module module-rtp-send source=MyNullSink.monitor loop=true
pacmd load-module module-rtp-recv
```

And then play something in the null sink, loopback sound will be horrible.

Any idea? (it was working well before with some Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 19 clients, still working on the ones I didn't upgraded).

The "Failed to set scheduler settings" makes me thing about realtime stuff, but what has changed with Ubuntu 20?

Update : Ubuntu 20 uses PulseAudio 13.99, aka PulseAudio 14 which implements RTP through gstreamer, to be followed...

Update: works fine when reading RTP stream with gst-launch :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=224.0.0.56 port=46586 caps="application/x-rtp, media=audio, payload=10, clock-rate=44100" ! .recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! pulsesink
```

So what is it that pulseaudio is not doing correctly?

Thanks;
Lionel

Comment: By bad, I mean lagging, like it's missing some RTP packets and there is a lof delay.

These PCs are different, that was working fine previously with Ubuntu 19 and 18. If using vlc as an RTP client then it works fine.

Comment: mmh llooks like Ubuntu 20 Pulseaudio packages are build on the to be released version 14, with rtp implemented through gstreamer, which is new.

Comment: [Bug created on Ubuntu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1878094)
[And finaly on PulseAudio gitlab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/889)

Comment: This is definitely a regression, not sure when it was introduced.  I've reviewed my configuration settings and I cannot find anything that has changed from before upgrading from 16.04 to 20.04.  Everything else in PulseAudio seems to work fine.

Comment: There is a work-around compiling these modules without gstreamer support, see Lionel Jeanson's thread comment on the above GitLab Issues link.

Comment: I've confirmed that Lionel Jeanson's solution works on both my RTP sender and receiver 20.04 machines.